# Use JQuery to change style for groups of elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to make a ul that changes background colors in groups of 4 li's (zebra striping but I want to be able to apply the background color once in the css and then access it with JQuery).  I don't want to just use something like nth-child because li's may need to be removed periodically, and I want the layout to remain without having to go in and change the class for each li.  I'm not sure if this makes sense, but I've put together an example html to try to show what I'm talking about.

I'd appreciate any possible suggestions for how to change the style (from white to grey background) at every fourth element (li).

Here are the styles:

```
li.grey {
background-color: #b9b9b9;
}

li.white {
background-color: #ffffff;
} 

.items_layout {
padding: 0 0 0 0;
width: 580px;
}  

.item_container {
color: #212D31;
overflow: hidden;
width: 580px;
}

.item_container li {
float: left;
width: 131px;
height: 130px;
padding: 2px; 5px 5px 5px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color: red;
list-style: none;
}

 .sample_header {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 0 1px 0;
  color: #0071B5;
  }
```

And here's the html:

```
 <div class="items_layout">
    <ul class="item_container">

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    White background<br />(background-color: #ffffff)</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    White background<br />(background-color: #ffffff)</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    White background<br />(background-color: #ffffff)</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    White background<br />(background-color: #ffffff)</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    Grey background<br />(background-color: #b9b9b9;)<br />starts here</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    Grey background<br />Should go here</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    Grey background<br />Should go here</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    Grey background<br />Should go here</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    Back to<br /> white background here</li>

                    <li><p class="sample_header">Header</p>                     
                    Back to<br /> white background here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help or thoughts on this.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use nth-child() in CSS instead? Then it'll update automatically if your HTML changes.

Comment: do you want highlighting on every 4th `li` or in blocks of 4 `li`

Comment: blocks of 4 li's- so that if an li is removed no changes need to be made to the remaining li's, but the styling stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple iterate over all li elements and set the background seems to be the easier. You may need to call this method whenever you add/remove elements from the list.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/cKBC2/1/)** here.

**JS Function:**

```
var isWhite = true;
$('ul.item_container > li'). each (function (index) {
    isWhite = (index != 0 && index % 4 ==0)? !isWhite:isWhite;
    if(isWhite == false) {
        $(this).removeClass('white').addClass('grey');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('grey').addClass('white');
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect- that's exactly what I was envisioning for this- thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the LI collection, and while you are doing it keep trak of a counter that goes from 1 to 4 and set class1, when it hits the number 4 change the class you are applying.